# Django DateTimeField to a day hour minute second

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm using http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. Each 'Event' table in my database has a 'date' column. `date = models.DateTimeField()`
The datetimefield( `{{ event.date }}`) will return '`Aug. 15, 2012, 12:23 p.m.`'. 
The default plugin format is 'dHMS'.

How do I get my django date to properly display within this jquery plugin? Or better yet. How do I turn my datetimefield into a:

```
 {{ countdown_day }},
 {{ countdown_hour }},
 {{ countdown_min }},
 {{ countdown_sec }} ?
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
(function(){
     var eventDate = '{{ event.date }}'; 
     $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: eventDate});      
     $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() { 
         $(this).text('Re-attach'); 
         $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy'); 
     }, 
    function() { 
        $(this).text('Remove'); 
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: eventDate}); 
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format a Python date into a Django template using the 'date' filter ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date)).

```
day:     {{ countdown|date:"D" }}
hour:    {{ countdown|date:"g" }}
minute:  {{ countdown|date:"i" }}
second:  {{ countdown|date:"s" }}
```

To turn the date into a javascript date, I use {{ countdown|date:"U" }} to get the unix timestamp. You can create a javascript date object from this as follows:

```
 new Date({{ countdown|date:"U" }} / 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking into `isoformat()`, but this seems to better suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually to obtain a correct date the code is:

```
new Date({{ countdown|date:"U" }} * 1000);
```

Because Django return time in seconds, and JS expect time in milliseconds.

[Javascript Date object definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)